# Data rw coverage analysis

Tags: c, gcc

Is it possible to instruct gcc to generate stats for static data access? ie on every access to a static memory location would either increment a read counter or write counter for that line of code and then this data can be displayed in a similar way to how code coverage data is displayed in lcov reports.

Comment: What's the use case for this?

Comment: What do you mean with `static data access` ?

Comment: The use case is making sure that data is being referenced. Using traditional coverage I can make sure that all code is being unit tested, but even if the code is unit tested I can not guarantee that all possible array members (or say configurations) in a module have been tested because code coverage will show 100% but only one or two data members in a static struct array may have been accessed so essentially all possible variations have not been tested. Therefore I don't want the coverage to report 100% in that case to make programmer aware that more tests are needed.

Comment: I say static access because usually this will be used just for const static arrays that essentially are part of the module and define different configuration profiles (or similar stuff). I don't like the idea of global nonconstant variables anyway and I can see that testing access to every single memory location may be tricky and even pointless.